# Finding the end of a zlib compressed stream

Tags: c++, c, qt, networking, zlib

I'm working on an NMDC client (p2p, DC++ and friends) with Qt. The protocol itself is pretty straightforward:

```
$command parameters|
```

Except for [compression](http://www.teamfair.info/wiki/index.php?title=ZPipe0):

> "ZPipe works by sending a command $ZOn| to the client. After $ZOn a ZLib compressed stream containing commands will follow. This stream will end with an EOF that ZLib defines. (there is no $ZOff in the compressed stream!)"

Here's the relevant code:

```
QTcpSocket *conn;
bool compressed;
QByteArray zbuffer;
QByteArray buffer;

// ...

void NMDCConnection::on_conn_readyRead() {
    // this gets called whenever we get new data from the hub

    if(compressed) {            // gets set when we receive $ZOn
        zbuffer.append(conn->readAll());


        // Magic happens here


        if( stream_is_complete ) {
            buffer.append(uncompressed_stream);
            buffer.append(remainder_of_data);
            compressed = false;
        }
    } else { 
        buffer.append(conn->readAll());
    };
    parse(buffer);
}
```

So, how do I get the values for `stream_is_complete`, `uncompressed_stream`, and `remainder_of_data`? I can't look for the next '$' because the stream can contain it. I tried looking for something resembling an EOF in the zlib documentation, but there is no such thing, in fact, every stream ends with a seemingly random character.

I also played around with qUncompress(), but that wants a complete stream, nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using zlib directly?

Totally untested...

```
z_stream zstrm;
QByteArray zout;
// when you see a $ZOn|, initialize the z_stream struct
parse() {
    ...
    if (I see a $ZOn|) {
        zstrm.next_in = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.avail_in = 0;
        zstrm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.zfree = Z_NULL;
        zstrm.opaque = 0;
        inflateInit(&zstrm);
        compressed = true;
    }
}
void NMDCConnection::on_conn_readyRead() {
    if (compressed) {
        zbuffer.append(conn->readAll());
        int rc;
        do {
            zstrm.next_in = zbuffer.data();
            zstrm.avail_in = zbuffer.size();
            zout.resize(zstrm.total_out + BLOCK_SIZE);
            zstrm.next_out = zout.data() + zstrm.total_out;
            zstrm.avail_out = BLOCK_SIZE;
            rc = inflate(&zstrm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
            zbuffer.remove(0, zstrm.next_in - zbuffer.data());
        } while (rc == Z_OK && zstrm->avail_out == 0);
        if (rc == Z_STREAM_END) {
            zout.truncate(zstrm.total_out);
            buffer.append(zout);
            zout.clear();
            buffer.append(zbuffer);
            zbuffer.clear();
            compress = false;
            inflateEnd(&zstrm);
        }
        else if (rc != Z_OK) {
            // ERROR!  look at zstrm.msg
        }
    }
    else // whatever
}
```

This incrementally decompresses (inflates) from `qbuffer` to `qout`, and stops when `inflate` says "no more".

Maybe it would be better to borrow from [QuaZip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Hmm, an obvious improvement would be to keep flushing `zout` into `buffer` incrementally too -- that way you can start parsing even before the compressed stream has all arrived.  On the other hand, it would be bloody horrible to see a `$ZOn|` within a `$ZOn|`...

Answer (score 0):

The end of file is not special for zlib. The problem I see with your code is that you use "readAll()", which actually does not have any means of reporting "errors", such as end of file.

You should try to use "read()" instead, in a loop. If you read the stream and it returns 0 bytes read, you can be sure you've reached the end of stream (the other end has closed the connection). The buffer you've read, joining those of all the previous "reads" in the loop, will give you the complete buffer.

Comment: No, no, no. "End of file" on QTcpSocket would mean we got disconnected, and the disconnected() signal would be fired. readyRead() specifically means we have new parseable data. The EOF I'm looking for is the end of the compressed segment, where we resume normal uncompressed protocol.